# SSRS Report problem in wpf

Tags: wpf, reporting-services, reportviewer

```
DataTable reportData = this.GetReportData(startId, endId, empId, minAmount, reportType);


                ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

                reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "PDCL.ERP.Modules.Marketing.Reports.rptDoctorDetail.rdlc";  

                ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource();
                ds.Name = "DoctorDetail_Report";
                ds.Value = reportData;
                reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);


                reportViewer.RefreshReport();
                this.WindowsFrmHost.Child = reportViewer;
```

this is my code.I'm using SSRS but the viewer only shows but not any data. 
Why..?

Comment: Have you tried adding event handlers to ReportError or RenderingCompleted to see if any additional information is coming from the viewer control?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to call refresh report after the reportviewer is loaded into the view.

Here is my code which works (reportViewerHost is WindowsFormsHost, declared in UserControl using XAML)

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlReportViewModel report = (SqlReportViewModel)this.DataContext;
            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer reportviewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer();
            reportViewerHost.Child = reportviewer;
            reportviewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
            reportviewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = report.FileName;
            report.LoadReport(reportviewer.LocalReport);
            reportviewer.RefreshReport();
        }
```

in the LoadReport Method of the SqlReportViewModel, I am setting the datasource as

```
_report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataset.Name, tbl));
```

where _report is the reference to LocalReport object passed as an argument

```
LocalReport _report;
```

It took me a while to figure this out... hope this helps.. 
Good Luck..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
DataTable reportData = this.GetReportData(startId, endId, empId, minAmount, reportType); 
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports//abc.rdlc";
ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", reportData);
//DataSet1 is the datasetname of the datasource on the rdlc report
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
Reports.TReportViewer report = new Reports.TReportViewer(); 
//TReportViewer is the window of wpf application where i set the reportviewerhost.
report.reportViewerHost.Child = reportViewer;
```

hope it will answer your question.